# Removing Directions markers from the Google Maps API V3

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-markers

To remove a normal marker from a map, I understand you simply call marker.setMap(null), but when implementing the Google Maps directions services, it automatically adds markers A and B onto the map ( calculating directions from point A to point B ). I do not have control over these markers, so I cannot remove them in the normal way. So how can I remove these markers (I have custom markers on the map instead)?

Comment: I have exactly the same question.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing, but with the v2 API?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Set the `suppressMarkers` option to true when creating your `DirectionsRenderer` object and then the markers won't show up. You could also change the style or icon of the markers. See the API spec for [DirectionsRendererOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRendererOptions) for other properties you can set.

```
   ... 
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
   ...
```

*EDIT: It looks like the API changed a little bit since my original answer almost 6 years ago, so the answer from @joni-jones is now the correct way. I tweaked my example above to reflect that.*

Comment: There is no documented `.suppressMarkers` property of the DirectionsRenderer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm guessing that the API changed, seeing how it seemed to work for some people at first. But since the answer from @joni-jones has more up votes, it must have changed a few years ago.

Comment: Is there a way to change its position on map. I need them but not on their default position as it is conflicting with my design

Comment: The above solution didn't work for me but this one did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264072/how-to-remove-default-a-b-markers-on-google-maps-route-direction .

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar problem. The previous solution did not help me. But I tried this:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
```

And it's work.

Comment: Hi @joni this removes the infowindow and I am unable to add it and just add custom marker.