# How to remove default A B markers on google maps route direction

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: start, map: map, icon: 'start.png' });
var stopMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: stop, map: map, icon: 'stop.png' });

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {
 origin: start, 
 destination: stop,
 travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
 }
});
```

Hi, this script shows route from start point to stop point and i use custom icons, but defaults green A and B also appear. 
Question is how do i remove default A and B markers so i will see only my custom ones ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Directions markers from the Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932416/removing-directions-markers-from-the-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Try using the [*suppressMarkers*](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRendererOptions) option on the DirectionsRenderer to prevent the markers on the route from being displayed.  This should leave the markers that you have added directly to the map in place but not show those associated with the route.

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
```

Comment: Thanks alot for reply, could u help me with setting stroke color ? By default its bold fiolet, but i want normal red
i tried 

directionsDisplay.polylineOptions( { strokeColor: '#000000' } );

but this dont work

Comment: `var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 
                polylineOptions:{strokeColor:"#4a4a4a",strokeWeight:5}, 
                suppressMarkers:true });`

Comment: Excellent news! And it works! I start having millions of problems because you can't handle those 2 points - events and infoWindow.  
So, I supress them, draw new markers on these 2 tail positions, change the icon image for the same as they have and... et voilá! Now I have ful control on "points" A and "B". Thank you @tvanfosson

Comment: @tvanfosson but if suppressMarkers is true, then dragging feature becomes unstable. Can you see my post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45769485/1513701

Answer (score 5):

```
directionsDisplay.setOptions({
polylineOptions: {
            strokeWeight: 4,
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor:  'red' 
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
directionsRenderer.setMap(map); 
directionsRenderer.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
```