# Remove directions from google map api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map using API v3 which gets directions from one location to another.  The app works great but the window which gets the directions is an overlay on the map.  I'd like it so when this window is closed directions are removed from the map but other markers remain.

I have tried the following:

```
$('#content .close').live('click', function() {
$('#content').hide();
directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
directionDisplay.setMap(map);
return false;
});
```

This seems to hide the window as expected but doesn't do anything regards with removing directions from the map.

Any help is much appreciated.

Dave.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232756/remove-route-with-google-map question already solved! Firstly search than ask.

Comment: From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232756/remove-route-with-google-map try 
directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove route with google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232756/remove-route-with-google-map)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can change the map binding for the DirectionsRenderer to "null" to remove the direction overlay

```
directionDisplay.setMap(null);
```

Comment: Similarly if you are using a panel to show directions, you can clear that by doing `directionDisplay.setPanel(null);`

Comment: What if I want to use the same map to display another set of directions? I setMap on the renderer again? There has got to be a better way of doing this!

Answer (score 54):

You can try this, and not lose reference to the map

```
directionDisplay.set('directions', null);
```

Comment: This was a useful addition which helped me as I needed to maintain the reference. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like this should be marked as the answer.  The Google supported API documentation binds the directionsDistplay object to the map and panel on initialization.  So when manipulating the directions with on-page events, it seems to make more sense to clear the directions contents rather than unbind the connection with the map and panel.

Comment: This one is the best answer here: it allows to show/hide directions without reinitializing map.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use :
`directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});`

Answer (score 1):

That should read as:

```
directionDisplay.setMap(null);
```

Comment: I found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264072/how-to-remove-default-a-b-markers-on-google-maps-route-direction

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, this is what I needed:

```
// Clear past routes
    if (directionsDisplay != null) {
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        directionsDisplay = null;
    }
```

Comment: How is this any different from the other answers?

Comment: Jeez this was ages ago but I guess simply nulling the 'setMap' attribute wasn't enough and I had to null it's parent as well to get it working as required.

Answer (score -2):

Using `directionDisplay.setMap(null);` will remove the whole directions renderer overlay, including markers. If you just want to remove the routes keeping the markers you can use `setOptions` to change the options settings of DirectionsRenderer for `suppressPolylines` after initialization

```
directionsDisplay.setOptions({
    suppressPolylines: true
  });
```

(see also my other [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004367/2314737))

Comment: If you suppress poly lines then they will never be shown. Here the context of the question is different