# Remove Directions not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I'd like a javascript link that will remove the directions from my map.

Elsewhere on this forum 
[Remove directions from google map api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645920/remove-directions-from-google-map-api-v3) someone asked a similar question and had a solution 
- but the solution doesn't work for me.
Based on that I've tried:

```
 function clearDirections() {
directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
directionDisplay.setMap(null);
return false;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, that function creates a new renderer, and then displays it on no map. Ie it does nothing.

You need to keep a reference to the original directions display - so that you can the  setMap(null) - which will remove it from the map.

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out how to do that. My map is based on Google's example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex.html

Comment: If you provide a link to your map, maybe someone could help you. In that example, directionDisplay is already a global variable, although there is a typo, as it uses directionsDisplay later.

Comment: Brilliant! 
I had emulated the typo. 
I changed it to the conventional directionDisplay then this function did the trick:      
    'function clearDirections() {
    document.getElementById("directionsPanel").innerHTML ="";
    directionDisplay.setMap(null);
    return false;
     }' 
Thank you!

Comment: oops . I was still left with custom markers. Final Code: ' function clearDirections() {
    if (markerArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++ ) {
      markerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  
document.getElementById("directionsPanel").innerHTML ="";
directionDisplay.setMap(null);
return false;
 }'