# How to remove default A B markers on ngMap

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I am using ng-map in my angular application. in my map i am using directions but i don't need A and B points. please help me hide these markers.
i got one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264072/how-to-remove-default-a-b-markers-on-google-maps-route-direction)
 but it's not helping in ng-map.
thts,s how I apllied it.

```
<ng-map zoom="14"
    center="1135 Karamea-Kohaihai Rd, Kahurangi National Park, Tasman"
    style="height:90%" >
    <directions
      draggable="true"
      panel="p2"
      travel-mode="DRIVING"
      origin="1135 Karamea-Kohaihai Rd, Kahurangi National Park, Tasman"
      destination="Pier St, Jackson Bay, West Coast, New Zeland" suppressMarkers='true'>
    </directions>
    <custom-marker id="start"
      position="1135 Karamea-Kohaihai Rd, Kahurangi National Park, Tasman">
      <div> Start point </div>
    </custom-marker>
    <custom-marker id="end"
      position="Pier St, Jackson Bay, West Coast, New Zeland">
      <div> Ends point </div>
    </custom-marker>
  </ng-map>
```

or maybe i am not using it correctly.
check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DN8V8gQ58Dx8ex06pxK2?p=preview).
Help

Comment: you need path right just need to remove A B marker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marker Icons won't show up if You add

`suppress-markers="true"` in `<directions>` as below.

```
<ng-map zoom="14"
        center="1135 Karamea-Kohaihai Rd, Kahurangi National Park, Tasman"
        style="height:90%" >
        <directions
          draggable="true"
          suppress-markers="true"
          panel="p2"
          travel-mode="DRIVING"
          origin="1135 Karamea-Kohaihai Rd, Kahurangi National Park, Tasman"
          destination="Pier St, Jackson Bay, West Coast, New Zeland" suppressMarkers='true'>
        </directions>
        <custom-marker id="start"
          position="1135 Karamea-Kohaihai Rd, Kahurangi National Park, Tasman">
          <div> Start point </div>
        </custom-marker>
        <custom-marker id="end"
          position="Pier St, Jackson Bay, West Coast, New Zeland">
          <div> Ends point </div>
        </custom-marker>
      </ng-map>
```

**OR**

`options.suppressMarkers = true;` just before `var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(options);` In `ng-map.js`