# how to change the ng-map marker's text 'A' and 'B'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

Hi I want to change markup text of ng-map. It should display "start" and "end" instead of "A" and "B" respectively.

I did refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807409/how-to-remove-default-a-b-markers-on-ngmap), but no luck.
It shows both the text "start" and "A" on markup.

Also If you observe, distance between source and destination is not same as what actual google map shows.

So I have three questions here.

1) Change markup text "start" instead of "A"

2) Distance between source and destination

3) I want to show this map on click of button "Draw Map" using AngularJS.

Below is my code.

```js
var mainModule = angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute', 'ngMap']);
 mainModule.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.sources = ["mumbai", "pune", "bangalore", "delhi", "netherlands"];
  $scope.destinations = ["pune", "bangalore", "mumbai", "delhi", "andorra"];
  $scope.origin = "mumbai";
  $scope.dest = "pune";
  $scope.drawMap = function(){
   var sourceVal = $('#sourceDdl').val();
   var destnVal = $("#destinationDdl").val();
   $scope.origin = sourceVal;
   $scope.dest = destnVal;
  }
  
 });
```

```css
body {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* google map */
.ng-map-section{
 width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border: 20px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>ng-map</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
    
 
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container ng-map-section" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
   <div style="float:left;width:70%;">
    <ng-map zoom="14" center="" style="height:600px">
     <directions 
      draggable="true" 
      travel-mode="DRIVING" 
      origin="{{origin}}" 
      destination="{{dest}}"
      suppressMarkers='true'>
     </directions>
     <custom-marker id="start" position="{{origin}}">
      <div> Start </div>
     </custom-marker>
     <custom-marker id="end" position="{{dest}}">
      <div> End </div>
     </custom-marker>
    </ng-map>
    
   </div>
   <div style="float:right;width:28%">
    <label for="sourceDdl">Source: </label>
    <select id="sourceDdl">
     <option ng-repeat="source in sources" value="{{source}}">{{source}}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label for="destinationDdl">Destination: </label>
    <select id="destinationDdl">
     <option ng-repeat="destination in destinations"  value="{{destination}}">{{destination}}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label>Distance: {{map.directionsRenderers[0].directions.routes[0].overview_path.length}}</label><br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="drawMap()" value="Draw Map">
   </div>
   <!--
   <div id="directions-panel" style="width: 28%; float:left; height: 100%; overflow: auto; padding: 0px 5px">
   </div>-->
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: you could create your own markers (as an image) and use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute should be `suppress-markers`, so replace `suppressmarkers='true'` with `suppress-markers="true"`

**Updated example**

```js
angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMap'])
    .controller('mapCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.sources = ["mumbai", "pune", "bangalore", "delhi", "netherlands"];
        $scope.destinations = ["pune", "bangalore", "mumbai", "delhi", "andorra"];
        $scope.origin = "mumbai";
        $scope.dest = "pune";
        $scope.drawMap = function() {
            var sourceVal = $('#sourceDdl').val();
            var destnVal = $("#destinationDdl").val();
            $scope.origin = sourceVal;
            $scope.dest = destnVal;
        }

    });
```

```css
body {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* google map */
.ng-map-section{
 width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border: 20px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>



    <div class="container ng-map-section" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <div style="float:left;width:70%;">
            <ng-map zoom="14" center="" style="height:600px">
                <directions 
                draggable="true" 
                travel-mode="DRIVING" 
                origin="{{origin}}" 
                destination="{{dest}}" 
                suppress-markers="true">
                </directions>
                <custom-marker id="start" position="{{origin}}">
                    <h3> Start </h3>
                </custom-marker>
                <custom-marker id="end" position="{{dest}}">
                    <h3> End </h3>
                </custom-marker>
            </ng-map>

        </div>
        <div style="float:right;width:28%">
            <label for="sourceDdl">Source: </label>
            <select id="sourceDdl">
                <option ng-repeat="source in sources" value="{{source}}">{{source}}</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="destinationDdl">Destination: </label>
            <select id="destinationDdl">
                <option ng-repeat="destination in destinations" value="{{destination}}">{{destination}}</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Distance: {{map.directionsRenderers[0].directions.routes[0].overview_path.length}}</label>
            <br>
            <input type="button" ng-click="drawMap()" value="Draw Map">
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, It worked. But red and green markups are gone after adding that attribute of 'directions'. It looks so dense over there. I need to maintain that as well. However I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

for 1) You can just add label="X"

Comment: Thanks Karsten, but where to add label="X". Plz suggest in my code.

Comment: <custom-marker id="start" label="X" position="{{origin}}">
<div> Start </div>
</custom-marker>

Comment: Unfortunately that (label="X") didn't work out. I wanna replace 'A' by "Start' and 'B' by 'End'. You can test http://plnkr.co/edit/YC2z4xH9ytdj0qc9w3lT?p=preview
what you suggested. It's not working.