# Google Map route dragging becomes unstable when suppressMarkers is set to true

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map where I can add multiple points/stops(waypoints) between source and destination route.

After the route is created (google.maps.DirectionsService) and put on the map (google.maps.DirectionsRenderer), you can drag the route middle-points to adjust the route as you wish -- draggable=true is set in the constructor of DirectionsRenderer.

```
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    draggable:true
});
```

The problem is when I change the route between two stops by dragging and later i again want to change the route by dragging same changed route point, it doesn't allow me.

But if I set `suppressMarkers: false`, then it works good.
Since I have to place custom marker I cannot mark `suppressMarkers` to true.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please supply a comment as to how this question might be improved.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?